# Android Volley - Waiting for multiple responses to complete and then do something

Tags: android, android-volley

So basically, I send 3 requests using volley to retrieve data from the database. I do this because I'm using different adapters instances to display each set of data. I send them in this order

1. `Request1`
2. `Request2`
3. `Request3`

I have put some code inside the `onResponse()` method of `Response3` which processes data retrieved from the previous requests too. So I need to wait for *all* responses to finish before I do any processing.

Here lies my problem though. There are times where `Request3` has the least data to retrieve, thus finishing faster than the others. So I get the responses like this:

1. `Response3`. Here my code which also processes data from `Response1` and `Response2` executes before those two have finished, thus getting wrong results.
2. `Response1`
3. `Response2`

If there is any way to wait for *all* responses to finish, I can put my processing code in that method. But I don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

simply write two methods:

**`executeSecondRequeset()`** which has `Response2`

**`executeThirdRequeset()`** which has `Response3`

and inside `OnResponse()` of your first request call `executeSecondRequeset()` that you declared and then in `OnResponse()` of that call `executeThirdRequeset()` method :)